# How to make send button "stick" to message input field at bottom of screen?

Tags: html, css, button, input, chat

I am making a chatroom app and I need the message input field to be inline with a send button, and for both of them to be at a fixed position on the bottom of the screen.

```
--------------------THIS IS THE HTML--------------------

<div class="msg-inputs">
        <input class="msg-input" type="text" rows="3" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message" onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event)" />
        <button class="send-btn" type="button" name="send" id="send-btn" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
      </div>
</div>

--------------------THIS IS THE CSS--------------------

.msg-inputs .msg-input[type=text] {
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #181818;
}

.msg-inputs .send-btn{
    background-color: #181818; 
    color: #ff9e3d;
    border: 2px solid #ff9e3d;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.send-btn:hover {
background-color: #ff9e3d;
color: white;
}
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Also, is there any way to get rid of the grey border around the message field's right and bottom side?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS:

```css
.msg-inputs{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}
        
.msg-inputs .msg-input[type=text] {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #ff9e3d;
  border: 2px solid black; /* or make 'none' */
}

.msg-inputs .send-btn{
    background-color: #181818; 
    color: #ff9e3d;
    border: 2px solid #ff9e3d;
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.send-btn:hover {
  background-color: #ff9e3d;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="msg-inputs">
      <input class="msg-input" type="text" rows="3" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message" onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event)" />
      <button class="send-btn" type="button" name="send" id="send-btn" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and the Send Button is misaligned with the msg-input field, do you have any idea why?

Comment: It's possible that one of your parent elements in HTML has a style that overrides the CSS I wrote.
Check if everything is active in DevTools in the browser.
Because in the example here everything works.